# Pandas Dataframes: how to build them efficiently

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a file with 1M rows that I'm trying to read into 20 DataFrames. I do not know in advance which row belongs to which DataFrame or how large each DataFrame will be. How can I process this file into DataFrames efficiently? I've tried to do this several different ways. Here is what I currently have:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'train.data', sep=" ", header = None) # Not slow
def collectData(row):
    id = row[0]
    df = dictionary[id] # Row content determines which dataframe this row belongs to
    next = len(df.index)
    df.loc[next] = row
data.apply(collectData, axis=1)
```

It's very slow. What am I doing wrong? If I just apply an empty function, my code runs in 30 sec. With the actual function it takes at least 10 minutes and I'm not sure if it would finish.

Here are a few sample rows from the dataset:

```
1 1 4
1 2 2
1 3 10
1 4 4
```

The full dataset is available [here](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/) (if you click on Matlab version)

Comment: could you elaborate the following: 1) what `data` looks like 2) what is the remainder of the line `data = pd.read...` 3) what does the source file look like (sample lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not a vectored one, because you apply a python function row by row.

Rather that creating 20 dataframes , make a dictionary containing an index (in range(20)) for each key[0].  Then add this information to your DataFrame:

```
 data['dict']=data[0].map(dictionary)
```

Then reorganize :

```
 data2=data.reset_index().set_index(['dict','index'])
```

data2 is like :

```
            0  1   2
dict index          
12   0      1  1   4
     1      1  2   2
     2      1  3  10
     3      1  4   4 
     4      1  5   2
     ....
```

and `data2.loc[i]` is one of the Dataframe you want.

**EDIT:**

It seems that dictionary is describe in `train.label`.

You can set the dictionary before by:

```
with open(r'train.label') as f: u=f.readlines()
v=[int(x) for x in u] # len(v) = 11269 = data[0].max()
dictionary=dict(zip(range(1,len(v)+1),v))
```

Comment: How do you actually create the dictionary? I've been trying variations of `dict.fromkeys(range(20), data.ix[:,0])` but I can not find a valid syntax.

Comment: I understood that dictionary was given. How do you want to split data ?

Comment: In the original code I had a dictionary where the keys were integers and the values were corresponding dataframes. I want to split data according to the id's that we get from row[0].

Comment: Probably. just describe your dictionary in the post. in particular : len(dictionnaries.values()). but what are these df in dictionary? empty ones ?

Comment: Yes, they were empty ones. So data[0] is DocId. Every DocId belongs to some group and there are 20 distinct groups. There is another file in the dataset which maps DocId to groupId's. The dictionary I had was supposed to return the corresponding group dataframe for any given DocId, essentially answering the question "which DataFrame should I place this row in?"

Comment: I see the relation in the `train.label` file. I will edit the post to exploit it.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's working. So we are setting data2 index to be composed of 2 columns, named "dict" and "index"? Are these indices nested somehow? Or why are we able to make a `loc` call with only 1 parameter, if the index consists of 2 columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134406/discussion-between-b-m-and-atte-juvonen).

Answer (score 2):

Since, the full data set is easily loaded into memory, the following should be fairly quick

```
data_split = {i: data[data[0] == i] for i in range(1, 21)}
# to access each dataframe, do a dictionary lookup, i.e.
data_split[2].head()
     0   1  2
769  2  12  4
770  2  16  2
771  2  23  4
772  2  27  2
773  2  29  6
```

you may also want to reset the indices or copy the data frame when you're slicing the data frame into smaller data frames.

additional reading:

- [copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)
- [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- [view-vs-copy](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: this way you will access only 0,17 % of the data, since data[0] can take 11269 values.

Comment: I think this answer will be very useful to other people even though it does not solve the problem I had.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to build them efficiently, I think you need some good raw materials:

- wood
- cement

Are robust and durable.
Try to avoid using hay as the dataframe can be blown up with a little wind.

Hope that helps